# Validate multiple text fields dependent on checkbox JS

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel

i have multiple checkbox with the same name attribute of `myTask` and multiple textfields named as `myWeight`

the value of `myTask` (`$field->taskCode`) is coming from db.

and the value of textfield `myWeight` is none.

Here's the code of it. **PHP/Laravel**

```
 @if(count($task_record))
 @foreach($task_record as $field)
 <div class="current-tl row">
     <div class="col-md-3">
          <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
               <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input myTask" name="myTask" value="{{$field->taskCode}}" id="myTask{{$field->taskCode}}">
                   <label class="custom-control-label" for="myTask{{$field->taskCode}}">{{$field->task_title}}</label>
                   </div>
                 </div>
                 <div class="col-md-4">
                 <div class="md-form svs-md-form">
                 <input type="number" placeholder="Task Weight" id="myWeight{{$field->taskCode}}" data-tcode = "{{$field->taskCode}}" name="myWeight" class="form-control">
               </div>
             </div>
         </div>
        @endforeach
   @else
   <label>No record found..</label>
   @endif
```

What I'm trying to do is to validate. If the user checks one of the checkboxes that corresponds to textfield will be automatically enabled and if not checked if will automatically disabled.

here's the current output

[image]

here's my current code to get the current value of checkbox and textfields **jQuery**

```
var taskData = []; 
$("input:checkbox[name=myTask]:checked").each(function() { 
    taskData.push($(this).val()); 
}); 


var dataWeight = []; 
$('input[name="myWeight"]').each(function() {
    if($(this).val() != ''){
        dataWeight.push($(this).val());
    }
});
```

Is that possible using javascript?

Comment: I don't understand what you want to do? Validate that there is a proper weight for each checked task?

Comment: In that case there's no weight for each task. I only fetch the taskCodes with empty text fields. Because the admin will register the weight for each task in this case.

Comment: What I'm trying to do is to disable or enable the text fields of `myWeight`

Comment: Ok, so just to be sure, you want to enable/disable the weight input if the associated checkbox is not checked?

Comment: Yes that's what I'm trying to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should create a check/validation function that you would run when your page loads, and then binded on each task checkbox. Since you seem to have proper ids everywhere from your backend, you could rely on them for your id names and selectors.

```js
var check = function ($checkbox) {
  $('#myWeight'+$checkbox.val()).prop('disabled', !$checkbox.is(':checked'));
};

$('input[type=checkbox]').each(function () {
  check($(this));
  
  $(this).on('change', function () {
    check($(this));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="current-tl row">
     <div class="col-md-3">
          <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
               <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input myTask" name="myTask" value="42" id="myTask42">
                   <label class="custom-control-label" for="myTask42">Task 42</label>
                   </div>
                 </div>
                 <div class="col-md-4">
                 <div class="md-form svs-md-form">
                 <input type="number" placeholder="Task Weight" id="myWeight42" data-tcode = "42" name="myWeight" class="form-control">
               </div>
             </div>
         </div>
         <div class="current-tl row">
     <div class="col-md-3">
          <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
               <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input myTask" name="myTask" value="43" id="myTask43">
                   <label class="custom-control-label" for="myTask43">Task 43</label>
                   </div>
                 </div>
                 <div class="col-md-4">
                 <div class="md-form svs-md-form">
                 <input type="number" placeholder="Task Weight" id="myWeight43" data-tcode = "43" name="myWeight" class="form-control">
               </div>
             </div>
         </div>
```

Comment: Works fineee.. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work (not tested):

```
$('.myTask').change(function() {
    var weightId = this.attr('id').replace('myTask', 'myWeight');
    $(`#${weightId}`).disabled = !this.checked;
})
```

- Get the array of elements with the class `myTask`
- Add an event listener for when the checkbox is toggled
- Grab the `input` element and disable it if the checkbox is not checked (or vice versa)